# make the gearman happen bugs

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gearman

I install gearman in `Ubuntu 14.04 64`

1. sudo wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-   1.1.12.tar.gz
2. sudo tar xvzf gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
3. cd gearmand-1.1.12/
4. sudo ./configure
5. sudo make

Bugs:

```
make -j5  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/gearman/gearmand-1.1.12'
CXX      libgearman-
server/plugins/queue/postgres/libgearman_server_libgearman_server_la-
queue.lo
libgearman-server/plugins/queue/postgres/queue.cc:55:23: fatal error: libpq-
fe.h: No such file or directory
# include <libpq-fe.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.

make[1]: *** [libgearman-
server/plugins/queue/postgres/libgearman_server_libgearman_server_la-
queue.lo] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/gearman/gearmand-1.1.12'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try install libpq-dev with apt-get and then configure again.